# I am receiving an error when I run NPM start

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

when running

```
npm start
```

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

Here is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

I am really new to this and I am very lost on what to do, I appreciate any answers. I checked at least 5 previous stack questions about this and I was not able to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js"
}
```

there is no "scripts" in your package.json. please look at https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values

change your package.json like this

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: what I am not understanding is where I add this in my package.json

Answer (score 1):

You need a script in your package.json

```
 {
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {   <-------
      "command_name": "command to run such as nodemon app.js
  }
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I put this in the json validator and I tested it in my code and I am getting errors. For  "command name" line, I did "start": "node your-script.js"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the start script in your package.json. Since this is a react project, you can use the `react-scripts` package to start your app.

```
{
    "name": "react-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: what I am not understanding is where I add this in my package.json

Comment: @apsasha I've updated the script with the entire `package.json` file content

Comment: Thank you so much, it still had one tiny error which would be fixed by adding a comma after the } above "dependencies. You really helped, I appreciate it!